# Как реализовать Filter с ограниченным доступом к определенным страницам Java EE

Tags: java, filter

Необходимо реализовать фильтр, который будет брать логин из сессии, смотреть его наличие и в случае, если его не существует- ограничить доступ к определенным страницам. 
Как это можно сделать?

```
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
                       FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
          HttpSession session=((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession();
         if(session.getAttribute("login")==null){
           //???
          }
  }
```

Comment: если не найдено редиректить на страницу по умолчанию `response.sendRedirect("/")` (привести resp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше брать из сессии не логин, а объект класса `User` (у которого есть поля id, login, password, ...).

Для этого нужно реализовать фильтр, который будет проверять: прошел ли пользователь аутентификацию (наличие объекта в сессии) и не находиться ли пользователь на странице входа или регистрации (иначе фильтр будет вечно перенаправлять). Если нет, то перенаправить пользователя на страницу login.jsp. Да - выполнить следующий фильтр или сервлет. И привязать его (в файле web.xml) к страницам, к которым доступ ограничен:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>здесь перечислить все страницы, к которым доступ ограничен</url-pattern>
<filter>
```

Сам фильтр:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    @Override public void init(FilterConfig config) {}
    @Override public void destroy() {}
    @Override public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,
                                   ServletResponse res,
                                   FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login";
        String registrURL = request.getContextPath() + "/registr";

        boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null;
        boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL) || request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL + ".html");
        boolean registrRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(registrURL) || request.getRequestURI().equals(registrURL + ".html");

        if(loggedIn || loginRequest || registrRequest) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: случайно не существует урл-паттерна вроде "все, кроме.."?
Допустим, страниц у меня очень много, а доступ хочу предоставить только к "зарегистрироваться" и "авторизоваться" или, может, еще на какую-то страницу

Comment: @VladislavSolopov, к сожалению не существует. Но можно поступить следующим образом: страницы регистрации и авторизации разместить в корневой папке, страницы для авторизованных пользователей разместить в папке _user_ и "смапить" их _url-pattern_-ом `/user/*`, для админа - `/admin/*` и т. д. Думаю идею Вы поняли.